# How to create a data (or preferabbly newtype) wrapper for a constrained function?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to create a type that holds a particular class of functions. Hopefully this is the right way to go about it (maybe `newtype` would be better? but I'm using GADTs):

```
data TraversableFun t a where
  TraversableFun :: Traversable t => (t a -> a) -> TraversableFun (t a -> a)
```

This results in the error:

```
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘TraversableFun (t a -> a)’
      Expected a type, but ‘TraversableFun (t a -> a)’ has kind ‘k0 -> *’
    • In the type ‘TraversableFun (t a -> a)’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘TraversableFun’
      In the data declaration for ‘TraversableFun’
   |
55 |   TraversableFun :: Traversable t => (t a -> a) -> TraversableFun (t a -> a)
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something similar here, maybe I should just sleep on it, but it's 5 PM on a Friday.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do, but the error seems clear enough: your constructor needs to return something of the form `TraversableFun t a` for two concrete types `t` and `a`. Perhaps you mean it to return a `TraversableFun (t a -> a) a` (or, I would have thought, just a `TraversableFun t a`. I'm not sure what you gain in that case by using GADTs though).

Comment: @RobertZigmond By using a GADT one would gain the `Traversable t` constraint

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - thanks, I'd missed that important point

Comment: @RobinZigmond, yes, I needed to return a `TraversableFun t a`. No more programming for me today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobinZigmond pointed out in the comments, you've defined `TraversableFun` as a type constructor with two parameters.  So, `TraversableFun (t a -> a)` doesn't have enough parameters to be a proper type that you can use as a result type for the `TraversableFun` constructor.  It's as if you've written `myFunction :: Int -> Either String` -- there's no such type as `Either String`, so it can't be a return type of a function.

If `TraversableFun` is just supposed to be a wrapper around `t a -> a`, then you probably just want `Traversable t a`.  The idea is that the constructor `TraverableFun` takes a function of type `t a -> a` and returns a wrapped value of the type `TraversableFun t a`.  So, quite literally:

```
TraversableFun :: Traversable t => (t a -> a) -> TraversableFun t a
```

However, there's probably no advantage to writing this as a GADT versus just using a newtype:

```
newtype TraverableFun t a = TraversableFun (t a -> a)
```

which is literally the same as the GADT:

```
newtype TraversableFun t a where
  TraversableFun :: (t a -> a) -> TraversableFun t a
```

While this newtype doesn't enforce a `Traversable t` constraint, it's generally agreed that functions should enforce constraints, not data types.  (If your GADT had multiple constructors with different constraints enforced by different constructors, then that would potentially be a different.)